# How can I pass common variables to all the views in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am working on a **[blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0/compare/main...themes)** in Laravel 8.

I have a `settings` table from which I pull the variables related to the site settings.

In the `FrontendController`I have:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Settings;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FrontendController extends Controller
{
    protected $theme_directory;
    protected $site_name;
    protected $tagline;
    protected $owner_name;
    protected $owner_email;
    protected $twitter;
    protected $facebook;
    protected $is_cookieconsent;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $settings = Settings::first();
        $this->theme_directory = $settings->theme_directory ?? null;
        $this->site_name = $settings->site_name ?? null;
        $this->tagline = $settings->tagline ?? null;
        $this->owner_name = $settings->owner_name ?? null;
        $this->owner_email = $settings->owner_email ?? null;
        $this->twitter = $settings->twitter ?? null;
        $this->facebook = $settings->facebook ?? null;
        $this->is_cookieconsent = $settings->is_cookieconsent ?? null;
    }
}
```

In the `ArticlesController` controller:

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Article;

```
class ArticlesController extends FrontendController {

    public function index() {
        $articles = Article::all();
        return view('themes/' . $this->theme_directory . '/templates/index', 
            [
                'site_name' => $this->site_name,
                'tagline' => $this->tagline,
                'articles' => $articles
            ]
        );
    }

    public function show($slug) {
        $article = Article::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        return view('themes/' . $this->theme_directory . '/templates/single', 
            [
                'site_name' => $this->site_name,
                'tagline' => $this->tagline,
                'article' => $article
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

#### The problem

The settings variables are repeated in every method of the `ArticlesController` controller:

```
'site_name' => $this->site_name,
'tagline' => $this->tagline,
```

##### How can I avoid this code repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use View Composers in Laravel. In AppServiceProvider or ViewServiceProvider `boot()` method:

```
View::composer('components.*', function ($view) {
    $settings = Setting::all();
    $view->with('settings', $settings);
});
```

It will send `$settings` to any blade file inside `resources/views/components` folder.